# Math/physics d=rt question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A runner completed the first half of a race at the speed of 2V, at what average speed must he run the second half to get a total average speed of V for the entire distance.

1) 1/2V

2) 2/3V

3) 3/4V

4) zero

I get zero but I'm not sure if takes into account have to finish race/I'm missing something key
(Sorry not sure what tag to use)

Comment: If the runner runs at 0V, he won't finish the race. Try doing the problem again and tell me what you get.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm thinking, but I'm not sure how to do the problem and have spent quite the time doing it

Comment: I posted a simple solution, if you need any more elaboration just comment

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: @anomaly I suggested an edit that improves the title

Answer (score 5):

I would just plug in a number for V. Here I will use 12mph for V and 12 miles for the racetrack, just to make it simple. If the runner completed the first half of the race at $2V=24$mph, it would take him $15$ minutes. If his average speed is going to be V, the time he finishes the second half of the race in is $60-15=45$minutes. To finish 6 miles in 45 minutes, the runner would have to run at $6*1 \frac 13=8$mph, which is $\frac 23$ of 12. Therefore the answer would be $\frac 23V$.

Comment: The total has to average out to V though, maybe I missed it but does yours include that.

Comment: Where is the 60 from

Comment: Yes, I explained it in the solution. The 60 is one hour, because if V is 12mph and the track is 12 miles, for an average speed of V it will take one hour to complete. This should answer both questions.

Comment: Do you get it now?

Comment: Yea I completely understand what you said and can tell is right, thanks! I'm just going to have to work through why what I did was wrong

Comment: No problem. If you include your attempt in your question I will attempt to explain where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Total average speed is not the average of the speeds in each part of the race. Instead, it's the total distance divided by the total time. Graphically, on a distance-time graph, it's the slope of the line connecting the beginning point to the end point (and not the average of the slopes of the intermediate line segments).

Let $D$ be the distance covered in each half of the race. Then since the first half of the race (a distance of $d_1 = D$) was completed at a constant speed of $v_1 = 2V$, the time for this first half was:
$$
t_1 = \frac{d_1}{v_1} = \frac{D}{2V}
$$
For the second half of the race (a distance of $d_2 = D$), we have:
$$
t_2 = \frac{d_2}{v_2} = \frac{D}{v_2}
$$
Now we know that in total, we have:
\begin{align*}
v_{\textsf{avg}} &= \frac{d_1 + d_2}{t_1 + t_2} \\
V &= \frac{D + D}{\frac{D}{2V} + \frac{D}{v_2}} \\
DV(\tfrac{1}{2V} + \tfrac{1}{v_2}) &= 2D \\
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{V}{v_2} &= 2 \\
\frac{V}{v_2} &= \frac{3}{2} \\
2V &= 3v_2 \\
v_2 &= \frac{2}{3}V
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks lots, helped me figure out why I was wrong. This is probably pretty obvious but can you quickly explain to me why this is true "Total average speed is not the average of the speeds in each part of the race. "

Comment: Oh cause different times I assume, I see.

Comment: Different speeds take different times, for example is someone walks 3 mph going uphill and 4 mph going downhill on a 24 mile hill (assuming the peak is in the middle) the average speed is not 3.5, but $\frac {24}7$